# ImageCapture.takePhoto throws DOMException: platform error

Tags: javascript, webapi, image-capture

Im trying to use the takePhoto method of image capture, using the following code.

```
addPicture: function (typeEvidence) {
    if ('mediaDevices' in navigator && 'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices) {
        this.typeEvidence = typeEvidence;
        var _self = this;
        this.initializeCamera();
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" } })
            .then(mediaStream => {
                _self.video.srcObject = mediaStream;
                _self.video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                    _self.video.play();
                };
                _self.track = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
                _self.imageCapture = new ImageCapture(_self.track);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                $.MenssagesGrowl.Show(3, 'Error: ' + err.name + ' - ' + err.message);
            });
        $("#modalAddPicture").modal("show");
    }
    else {
        $.MenssagesGrowl.Show(3, 'The browser does not support media devices');
    }
},    
initializeCamera: function () {
        var _self = this;
        this.dataURL = '';
        this.disableTakePicture = true;
        this.blob = null;
        this.streaming = false;
        this.imageCapture= null;
        this.video = document.querySelector('video');
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('cameraCanvas');
        this.video.addEventListener('canplay', (ev) => {
            if (!_self.streaming) {
    
                _self.picWidth = _self.video.videoWidth;
                _self.picHeight = _self.video.videoHeight;
                //_self.picWidth = _self.video.videoWidth / (_self.video.videoHeight / _self.picHeight);
    
                // Firefox currently has a bug where the height can't be read from
                // the video, so we will make assumptions if this happens.
    
                if (isNaN(_self.picWidth)) {
                    _self.picWidth = _self.picHeight / (4 / 3);
                }
    
                _self.video.setAttribute('width', _self.picWidth);
                _self.video.setAttribute('height', _self.picHeight);
                _self.canvas.setAttribute('width', _self.picWidth);
                _self.canvas.setAttribute('height', _self.picHeight);
    
                _self.streaming = true;
                _self.disableTakePicture = false;
            }
        }, false);
        this.clearPhoto();
    },
    takePicture: function () {
        var _self = this;
        this.imageCapture.takePhoto(null)
            .then((blob) => {
                return Promise.all([createImageBitmap(blob),blob]);
            })
            .then((result) => {
                //result[0] bitmap
                //result[1] blob
                //guardar foto
                var _sequence = _self.getConsecutiveForFileName();
                var _filename = _self.PrevioHeader.ControlNum + "_" + _self.PreviousConsignment.ConsignmentNum + "_" + _sequence + ".png";
                var _file = new File([result[1]], _filename, {
                    type: 'image/png'
                });
                var _formData = new FormData();
                _formData.append("image", _file);
                _formData.append("id", _self.PreviousConsignment.Guid);
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: this.url,
                    data: _formData,
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
                }
                ).then((response) => {
                    if (response.data.result == true) {
                        $.MenssagesGrowl.Show(response.data.typeMessage, response.data.message);
                        var _context = _self.canvas.getContext('2d');
                        if (_self.picWidth && _self.picHeight) {
                            _self.canvas.width = _self.picWidth;
                            _self.canvas.height = _self.picHeight;
                            _context.drawImage(result[0], 0, 0, _self.picWidth, _self.picHeight);
                            var _dataURL = _self.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                            _self.PreviousConsignment.Images.push({
                                dataURL: _dataURL,
                                fileName: _filename,
                                id: response.data.id,
                                sequence: _sequence,
                                typeEvidence: _self.typeEvidence,
                                temporal: 1
                            });
                        }
                        else
                            _self.clearPhoto();
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
```

The application was working ok with the following line

> this.imageCapture.takePhoto()

, but suddenly stopped working today throwing a generic error **DOMException: platform error**.
I did a little bit of research and realized they had made a change a year ago to use it as

> takePhoto(photoSettings)

as the documentation in [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/takePhoto) says, since photoSettings is optional i tried to use

> this.imageCapture.takePhoto(null)

and it worked for a while until later this day, when it started throwing again the same error.
Does anyone knows the reason, is the ImageCapture not stable for production and if it is not is there an alternative or workaround?

Im running the app under chrome and using vue as framework.

Comment: Please show how you initiate the ImageCapture and its input MediaStreamTrack.

Comment: Done, yeah i forgot that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 1/31/2023:**
Chrome is now actively working on fixing this issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1287227

It appears updating Chrome doesn't fix the issue, because Chrome is feature flag testing `MediaFoundationD3D11VideoCapture`.  When `MediaFoundationD3D11VideoCapture` is disabled, the issue doesn't occur.

**Original Answer 1/12/2023**

My customers started getting this error on 1/12/2023.  I think Chrome released a version with a bug in the webcam APIs.

I had them update their version of chrome and it immediately started working again. The version that fixed it was v109.0.5414.75

**To update chrome:**

[image: Update Chrome]

**Version that worked for me:**

[image: Version that worked]

Comment: Not the first itme it has happened to me but it was more persistant this time, could it be really that is a version bug?

Comment: Updating chrome fixed it for most of my machines.  There is still one machine that is getting the "platform error" message after updating. It looks like based on the source code this is the line that is failing: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/6a986948a587cc5a45db73984329ee56d669a058/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/imagecapture/ImageCapture.cpp#634, "photo_state.is_null()". I hope this is answered soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
await imageCapture.grabFrame()
```

which will return a Promise that resolves to an `ImageBitMap` object, then pass it to `await createImageBitmap(ImageBitMap_object)` and convert the image `Bitmap` to `Canvas`, then draw it to it and use `canvas.toBlob` to save the image!

[image: Have created a separate function to download the image which is given in second ss]